# Android Read Images Permission External Storage

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-image, android-internal-storage

I want to read and save Images / Bitmaps from internal storage.

In my layout I have a button and a imageview. When I click the button I want to chose a picture of the gallery to save it. When I click on the imageview I want the saved image to be shown.

Thats what I tried:

**Layout:**

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:text="Upload Image"
        android:onClick="onClickUpload"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPicker"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:onClick="onClickShow"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
```

**Read function with asking for permission**

```
public void onClickUpload(View view) {

    // request permission to read external storage (explicit necessary since API Level 23)

    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(DetailActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(DetailActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DetailActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
            }
    } else {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), GET_FROM_GALLERY);
    }
}
```

**Override onRquestPermissionResult**

```
/*
    find out whether the permission was granted
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // start Activity if granted
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), GET_FROM_GALLERY);

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

**Run after permission granted:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //Detects request codes
    if(requestCode==GET_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);

            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
            // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
            File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            // Create imageDir
            File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
                // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            directory.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In my **manifest** I have also permissions:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".activities.LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.RegisterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CategoryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.SuggestionActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.DetailActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</application>
```

Nevertheless I get this **error** when clicking the button (Device is API 24):

```
06-08 19:56:28.903 18770-18782/android.process.media E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                                                      java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/file from pid=20240, uid=10046 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:608)
                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:483)
                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:212)
                                                                          at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
                                                                          at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), GET_FROM_GALLERY);
```

The above code is executed regardless of the permission being granted or not. Did you mean to wrap it around `else` for your `if`?

```
public void onClickUpload(View view) {

    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(DetailActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(DetailActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DetailActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    } else {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), GET_FROM_GALLERY);
    }
}
```

And I'm assuming you've overridden

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults)
```

for listening to the permission being granted or not.

Comment: Well. Yeah. This code should only start if I have the permission to read external storage. That's true. The code starts every time. Means I go the the gallery. There is no permission dialog before it... Doesn't the dialog has to start anyway?

Comment: I think your app crashes before it tries to attach the dialog. hence you don't see it.

Comment: I overwrite onRequestPermissionResult (code added in the description). After updating my code to your version I get following log: 1611-8222/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS pkg=com.google.android.packageinstaller cmp=com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10082 on display 0 - but nothing more happens?

Comment: your `if` block for request granted is blank. Don't you want to start the activity if the permission is granted? Add `startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), GET_FROM_GALLERY);` to the `if` block if it's granted.

Comment: That is pretty strange. I have the permission: if (grantResults.length > 0
 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ...is true, but I get permission denial anyway (code run like updated in the description)

Comment: I don't quite understand. Even when you accept the permission, the activity is not started? What happens then?

Comment: I don't get any dialog window but I just tried some msg in the if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) to know if we are getting so far. We do, but we get an error with permission denied in log. I added the code run after we know that permission was granted. Maybe here is the problem?